# convert dataframe to a dictionary with key and list of dictionary as values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I wish to convert the below dataframe to a nested dictionary

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame([{
  'id': "qt1",
  'email': 'tim@apple.com',
  'company_name': "11-50",
  'first_name': "aram",
  'last_name': "lord",
  'title': "ceo"},
 {'id': "qt2",
  'email': 'aaron@unke.com',
  'company_name': "unke3",
  'first_name': "mich",
  'last_name': "smith",
  'title': "vp"},
 { 'id': "qt3",
  'email': 'dar@tryiu.com',
  'company_name': "triop",
  'first_name': "sela",
  'last_name': "augus",
  'title': "cfo"}])
```

that looks like this

```
{'enrichments': [
    {'id': 'qt1', 'email': 'tim@apple.com', 'company_name': 'Apple', 'first_name': 'aram', 'last_name': 'lord', 'title': 'ceo',}, 
    {'id': 'qt2','email': 'aaron@unke.com', 'company_name': 'unke3', 'first_name': 'mich', 'last_name': 'smith', 'title': 'vp',}, 
    {'id': 'qt3','email': 'dar@tryiu.com', 'company_name': 'triop', 'first_name': 'sela', 'last_name': 'augus', 'title': 'cfo',}
    ],}
```

I tried using groupby and to_dict, but it did not work. Any suggestions? Thanks up front for the help.

Comment: `df.to_dict("records")` is almost there

Comment: thats the challenge i am facing, i need it in the format provided.

Comment: Nyquist has it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_dict` with a different orientation:

```
new_dict = {'enrichments': df_2.to_dict(orient='records')}
```

gives:

```
{'enrichments': [{'id': 'qt1', 'email': 'tim@apple.com', 'company_name': '11-50', 'first_name': 'aram', 'last_name': 'lord', 'title': 'ceo'}, 
{'id': 'qt2', 'email': 'aaron@unke.com', 'company_name': 'unke3', 'first_name': 'mich', 'last_name': 'smith', 'title': 'vp'}, 
{'id': 'qt3', 'email': 'dar@tryiu.com', 'company_name': 'triop', 'first_name': 'sela', 'last_name': 'augus', 'title': 'cfo'}]}
```